# Calculate a Limit and find the Sup

Tags: limits, holder-spaces

Supporse that 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha+1},\quad\alpha\in(0,1],x\in I:=[-1,1],
$$
and
$$
g(x,y)=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\beta},\quad x,y\in I.
$$
I can prove if 
$$
\sup_{x,y\in I}g(x,y)<+\infty,
$$
then one must require that $\alpha=\beta$.

My question is how to get the exact value of $\sup_{x,y\in I}g(x,y)$ in this case?

The first thing is that
$$
\lim_{\substack{x\to0 \\y\to 0}}g(x,y)=1,
$$
holds?